# ccavenue IFRAME integration using php

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I am trying to integrate **ccavenue IFRAME payment gateway** into my **wordpress** website. The ccavenue integration is working well except the IFRAME doesnt happen. I used a plugin provided by ccavenue. When I contacted the ccavenue guys they told me the plugin doesn't support IFRAME integration. Hence we are supposed to manually integrate it using the php kit provided by them. Using the php kit I do not know which file goes where and where to put the code. Help would be really appreciated.
The documentation is here

**Set Up:** 
Download the CCAvenue client library as instructed here. You will have to use the CCAvenue iframe code (e.g. transaction.jsp for JSP) to initiate the payment process.
**Configure:** 
Every merchant receives a unique set of keys for transaction processing. These need to be configured in the transaction file used to initiate the payment process.

From your MARS account under Settings tab > API Keys page; copy the merchant ID, access code and secret encryption.

You must integrate the iFrame code into your payment page to load the iFrame. Refer to the code below. You also need to set the keys in your payment file for processing the transaction.

**Payment Processing:**
On your payment page send a request to the CCAvenue PG with order information like merchant id, amount, currency, shipping information (optional) and billing information (optional) to load the CCAvenue iFrame. CCAvenue iFrame will display the payment options for customer to select.

For initiating the iframe add the following bit of code to your website checkout page. This code is available in the kit you download for integration purpose. The php kit contains the code

- ccavrequesthandler,
- ccaverequesthandler,
- ccavresponsehandler,
- crypto,
- dataform
- jquery.1.7.2

I haven't included the jquery file.

CCavrequesthandler

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title> Iframe</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <center>
 <?php include('Crypto.php')?>
 <?php 

  error_reporting(0);

  $working_key='';//Shared by CCAVENUES
  $access_code='';//Shared by CCAVENUES
  $merchant_data='';

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    $merchant_data.=$key.'='.$value.'&';
   }
   $encrypted_data=encrypt($merchant_data,$working_key);//Method for
                                                    encrypting the date.
     $production_url='https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/
      transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction&encRequest='
      .$encrypted_data.'&access_code='.$access_code;   
       ?>
       <iframe src="<?php echo $production_url?>"  
        id="paymentFrame" width="482" height="450" frameborder="0"
        scrolling="No"
         ></iframe>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
         window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
       $("#paymentFrame").css("height",e.data['newHeight']+'px');    
           }, false);

          });
      </script>
      </center>
  </body>
 </html>
```

CCaverequesthandler

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Iframe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<center>
  <?php include('Crypto.php')?>
 <?php 

error_reporting(0);

$working_key='';//Shared by CCAVENUES
$access_code='';//Shared by CCAVENUES
$merchant_data='';

 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    $merchant_data.=$key.'='.$value.'&';
   }

  $encrypted_data=encrypt($merchant_data,$working_key); // Method for   encrypting the data.

$production_url='https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction&encRequest='.$encrypted_data.'&access_code='.$access_code;
     ?>
      <iframe src="<?php echo $production_url?>" id="paymentFrame" width="482" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" ></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
                 $("#paymentFrame").css("height",e.data['newHeight']+'px');      
         }, false);

         });
           </script>
          </center>
         </body>
         </html>
```

CCaveresponsehandler

```
    <?php include('Crypto.php')?>
 <?php

error_reporting(0);

$workingKey='';     //Working Key should be provided here.
$encResponse=$_POST["encResp"];         //This is the response sent by the CCAvenue Server
$rcvdString=decrypt($encResponse,$workingKey);      //Crypto Decryption used as per the specified working key.
$order_status="";
$decryptValues=explode('&', $rcvdString);
$dataSize=sizeof($decryptValues);
echo "<center>";

for($i = 0; $i < $dataSize; $i++) 
{
    $information=explode('=',$decryptValues[$i]);
    if($i==3)   $order_status=$information[1];
}

if($order_status==="Success")
{
    echo "<br>Thank you for shopping with us. Your credit card has been charged and your transaction is successful. We will be shipping your order to you soon.";

}
else if($order_status==="Aborted")
{
    echo "<br>Thank you for shopping with us.We will keep you posted regarding the status of your order through e-mail";

}
else if($order_status==="Failure")
{
    echo "<br>Thank you for shopping with us.However,the transaction has been declined.";
}
else
{
    echo "<br>Security Error. Illegal access detected";

}

echo "<br><br>";

echo "<table cellspacing=4 cellpadding=4>";
for($i = 0; $i < $dataSize; $i++) 
{
    $information=explode('=',$decryptValues[$i]);
        echo '<tr><td>'.$information[0].'</td><td>'.$information[1].'</td></tr>';
}

echo "</table><br>";
echo "</center>";
?>
```

Crypto file

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

function encrypt($plainText,$key)
{
    $secretKey = hextobin(md5($key));
    $initVector = pack("C*", 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f);
    $openMode = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '','cbc', '');
    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'cbc');
    $plainPad = pkcs5_pad($plainText, $blockSize);
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($openMode, $secretKey, $initVector) != -1) 
    {
          $encryptedText = mcrypt_generic($openMode, $plainPad);
              mcrypt_generic_deinit($openMode);

    } 
    return bin2hex($encryptedText);
}

function decrypt($encryptedText,$key)
{
    $secretKey = hextobin(md5($key));
    $initVector = pack("C*", 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f);
    $encryptedText=hextobin($encryptedText);
    $openMode = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '','cbc', '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($openMode, $secretKey, $initVector);
    $decryptedText = mdecrypt_generic($openMode, $encryptedText);
    $decryptedText = rtrim($decryptedText, "\0");
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($openMode);
    return $decryptedText;

}
//*********** Padding Function *********************

 function pkcs5_pad ($plainText, $blockSize)
{
    $pad = $blockSize - (strlen($plainText) % $blockSize);
    return $plainText . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

//********** Hexadecimal to Binary function for php 4.0 version ********

function hextobin($hexString) 
 { 
        $length = strlen($hexString); 
        $binString="";   
        $count=0; 
        while($count<$length) 
        {       
            $subString =substr($hexString,$count,2);           
            $packedString = pack("H*",$subString); 
            if ($count==0)
        {
            $binString=$packedString;
        } 

        else 
        {
            $binString.=$packedString;
        } 

        $count+=2; 
        } 
        return $binString; 
      } 
 ?>
```

Data Form

```
    <html>
<head>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById("tid").value = d;
   };
</script>
 </head>
<body>
    <form method="post" name="customerData" action="ccavRequestHandler.php">
    <table width="40%" height="100" border='1' align="center"><caption><font size="4" color="blue"><b>Integration Kit</b></font></caption></table>
        <table width="40%" height="100" border='1' align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Parameter Name:</td><td>Parameter Value:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"> Compulsory information</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TID :</td><td><input type="text" name="tid" id="tid" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Merchant Id :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_id" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Order Id    :</td><td><input type="text" name="order_id" value="123654789"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount  :</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" value="1.00"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Currency    :</td><td><input type="text" name="currency" value="INR"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Redirect URL    :</td><td><input type="text" name="redirect_url" value="http://localhost/IFrame_PHP_kit/ccavResponseHandler.php"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cancel URL  :</td><td><input type="text" name="cancel_url" value="http://localhost/IFrame_PHP_kit/ccavResponseHandler.php"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Language    :</td><td><input type="text" name="language" value="EN"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Billing information(optional):</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Billing Name    :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_name" value="Charli"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Billing Address :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_address" value="Room no 1101, near Railway station Ambad"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Billing City    :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_city" value="Indore"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Billing State   :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_state" value="MP"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Billing Zip :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_zip" value="425001"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Billing Country :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_country" value="India"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Billing Tel :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_tel" value="9595226054"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Billing Email   :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_email" value="atul.kadam@avenues.info"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Shipping information(optional)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shipping Name   :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_name" value="Chaplin"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shipping Address    :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_address" value="room no.701 near bus stand"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>shipping City   :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_city" value="Hyderabad"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>shipping State  :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_state" value="Andhra"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>shipping Zip    :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_zip" value="425001"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>shipping Country    :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_country" value="India"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shipping Tel    :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_tel" value="9595226054"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Merchant Param1 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param1" value="additional Info."/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Merchant Param2 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param2" value="additional Info."/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Merchant Param3 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param3" value="additional Info."/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Merchant Param4 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param4" value="additional Info."/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Merchant Param5 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param5" value="additional Info."/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Promo Code  :</td><td><input type="text" name="promo_code" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vault Info. :</td><td><input type="text" name="customer_identifier" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Integration Type    :</td><td><input type="text" name="integration_type" value="iframe_normal"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td><INPUT TYPE="submit" value="CheckOut"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the kit for integration available.Download the CCAvenue client library as instructed here.You have not added any link there

Comment: We used this Laravel plugin. https://github.com/softon/indipay
CCAvenue also has nice Development Kit which you can download after loging in as merchant